On the permutation of vertex set and automorphism of graphs.
I’m novice in graph theory, I greatly appreciate if you find any mistake and edit that mistake.
Suppose I have a unlabelled simple, undirected, graph $G$. Vertex set consist of $N$ vertices. Now, we label that graph and the elements of vertex set are $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$. Now consider a permutation map $(1,\ldots,N)\mapsto (\pi(1),\ldots,\pi(N))$ and called all sets of permutation as $\mathcal{P}$.
Now, consider a automorphism $\phi\colon V(G)\to V(G)$. Now, fixing a symmetry $s$ in the set of all symmetry $S$, we can generate all possible automorphism fixing a particular symmetry.
My question is can I write
$$\mathcal{P}(G) = \bigcup_{\text{s$\in$ S}}\text{Aut}_{s}{G}$$
Example, Suppose my graph is an wedge or $2$-star. Then $\mathcal{P} = {(1,2)(1,3), (1,3)(1,2),(2,1)(2,3), (2,3)(2,1), (3,1)(3,2),(3,2)(3,1)}$. Now fixing symmetry of wedge, that is similar to fixing the vertex of degree 2 in wedge, we get $\text{Aut}_{1}(G) = \{(1,2)(1,3), (1,3)(1,2)\}$, $\text{Aut}_{2}(G) = \{(2,1)(2,3), (2,3)(2,1)\}$ and $\text{Aut}_{3}(G) = \{(3,1)(3,2), (3,2)(3,1)\}$, then
$$\mathcal{P}(\text{wedge}) = \bigcup_{i=1}^3\text{Aut}_{i}{\text{(wedge)}}$$
In the above example we consider reflection line through vertex $i$, that is that vertex working as a reflection symmetry of $2$-star.
This is based on my basic observation, I do not know, any theorem exist on this regards. I will greatly appreciate, if there is any reference or proof or any counter example exists.

What is $S$? And what do you mean by $Aut_s$?

@MatthewSpam I edited the question. hope that helps. Actually I tried to figure out whether we can generalise the given example or not.

What you've written for $\mathcal P$ is incorrect. There are 6 elements, but the 6 you've written contains duplicates. It's probably easier to think of $\mathcal P$ as containing $(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)$, and the identity.

I'm not 100% clear if this is what you're looking for, but if I understand correctly, then what you want will almost never hold.
As I understand, you are asking to write the permutations of the vertex set as a union of graph automorphisms. In fact, the set of automorphisms of a graph forms a group under composition, and it is a subgroup of the set of all permutations of the vertex set. That is, every graph automorphism induces a permutation of the vertex set, but it is not necessarily true that every permutation of vertices defines a graph automorphism.
In your example of a wedge, let us label the vertex of degree 2 by 1, and the other two vertices as 2 and 3. Then there are two permutations that give us graph automorphisms: The identity, and the permutation $(2, 3)$. The permutation $(1,2,3)$, for example, does not define a graph automorphism. In fact, since $1$ is the only vertex of degree 2, every graph automorphism has to fix it.
The only graphs with the property that every permutation of the vertices defines a graph automorphism are the complete graph and the graph with no edges.
